# Excel Item Name Search Match - 2 Open Files

Tags: search, excel, barcode, vba

I have been trying to approach a particular case, but have yet to know where to go from what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I found something which I wanted to try to see if I could build from it to my particular case here. I copied the contents from file2 to sheet3 instead of using two separate files to see if this too could work. But, after changing values around, I still got an error(Run time error 9. Subscript out of range)

Originally, I have two excel files.

File1 has item Names in columnE starting after A5 in sheet2. 
File2 has item Names in columnA starting after A3 in sheet1.

I want to write a macro that can place a number(Barcode) into ColumnD in file2, found from ColumnD in File1, for each cell value in ColumnA from file2 that matches cell value in ColumnE from file1.

In other words, File2 with item names in columnA that have no bar code in columnD, search list of all items in File1 ColumnE, find exact name match, from that same row copy value of column D containing barcode, paste barcode value into File2 empty columnD.

```
Sub Find_Barcode()

Dim PartRngSheet1 As Range, PartRngSheet2 As Range
Dim lastRowSheet1 As Long, lastRowSheet2 As Long
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

lastRowSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set PartRngSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSheet1)

lastRowSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set PartRngSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSheet2)

For Each cl In PartRngSheet1
    For Each rng In PartRngSheet2
        If (cl = rng) Or (cl = rng.Offset(0, 1)) Then
            rng.Offset(0, 4) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next rng
Next cl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :
Assuming File1 & File2 are two different workbooks and are open.

```
Sub Find_Barcode()

    Dim lastRow As Long, rngFind As Range, rngFound As Range
    lastRow = Workbooks("File2").Sheets("sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    Workbooks("File1").Activate
    Set rngFind = Workbooks("File1").Sheets("sheet2").Range("E5", Range("E65000").End(xlUp).Row)


    For i = 3 To lastRow

        Set rngFound = rngFind.Find(what:=Workbooks("File2").Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1))
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            rngFound.Offset(0, -1).Copy Workbooks("File2").Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 4)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh, thanks alot for your answer. I forgot to add, I am relatively new to VBA and I'm actually learning it as I am going right now, and this is my first problem to solve using this language. I am still trying to figure out the why's or the how's haha. I apologize for the slow response, but, I tried what you suggested. I still am getting an error. It's ok though. I appreciate your help! :)